# Extension of generic Java class does not recognize super constructor

Tags: java, generics

Can someone please help me understand why this Java code doesn't compile?

The idea is that `A` is a tree-like class for a type `T` that takes a collection of children at construction.

Then I define an extension `B` of `A` that specializes `T` for `Pair<R,R>`.

```
class A<T> {
    A(T t, Collection<? extends A<? extends T>> cOfAs) {

    }
}

class B<R> extends A<Pair<R,R>> { // Pair is just a POJO class
    B(Pair<R,R> pair, Collection<? extends B<? extends R>> cOfBs) {
        super(pair, cOfBs);
        // ERROR: The constructor A<Pair<R,R>>(Pair<R,R>, Collection<capture#1-of ? extends B<? extends R>>) is undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of the second parameter doesn't match.  The `B` constructor takes `Collection<? extends B<? extends R>>`, but the superclass constructor takes a `Collection<? extends A<? extends T>>`.

You've defined `T` to be `Pair<R, R>` in your `B` class, so instead of `R`, use `Pair<R, R>`.  Also the `? extends` part must match, so change `? extends B<...>` to `? extends A<...>`.  The signature of B's constructor now looks like this:

```
B(Pair<R,R> pair, Collection<? extends A<? extends Pair<R, R>>> cOfBs)
```

It must be `? extends A` exactly, because `? extends B` may not match `? extends A`.  The only way to get this to match is to introduce another type parameter in `A` representing the "self" type, and to use it in the second parameter of the constructor.

```
class A<T, S extends A<T, S>> {
    A(T t, Collection<? extends S> cOfAs) {

    }
}
```

Then in `B`, supply `B<R>` as "self".

```
class B<R> extends A<Pair<R,R>, B<R>> { // Pair is just a POJO class
    B(Pair<R,R> pair, Collection<? extends B<R>> cOfBs) {
        super(pair, cOfBs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What do you think of the use of `Collection<? extends B<R>> cOfBs` as suggested by another answer? It seems more natural.

Answer (score 1):

The type of second argument of constructor is wrong:

```
Error:(20, 25) java: incompatible types: java.util.Collection<capture#1 of ? extends Main.B<? extends R>> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<? extends Main.A<? extends javafx.util.Pair<R,R>>>
```

To fix it change second argument to  `Collection<? extends B<R>> cOfBs`